# Is there a way to prevent git clone from leaking basic auth token?

Tags: git

We're doing this in our automation that gets logged:

```
GIT_CLONE_URL_WITH_AUTH=${REPOSITORY_GIT_CLONE_HTTPS_URL//"https://"/$BASIC_AUTH}

git clone -q "$GIT_CLONE_URL_WITH_AUTH" "$GIT_CLONE_DIRECTORY"
```

We see this on error:

```
Cloning https://github.my-company.com/owner/repo...
fatal: unable to access 'https://x-access-token:v1.e3243f43f43575232e54a45f11fa4c81eaefd32e@github.my-company.com/owner/repo/': The requested URL returned error: 504
```

The only thing we came up with is using grep to hide the logging like so:

```
| grep -v -e "fatal: unable to access 'https://x-access-token:"
```

Kinda crappy that -quiet mode is leaking our basic auth.

Edit: This is the recommended way to use the git api as an installation of the github app. I use ssh for my day to day git operations...

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#http-based-git-access-by-an-installation

Comment: Do not put the toke into URLs. Instead use a credential manager. Or switch to `ssh://` protocol and use SSH key pair.

Comment: @phd this is authenticating using automation as a github app. It's the recommended way by github: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#http-based-git-access-by-an-installation

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid placing credentials in the URL.  This writes them to disk and isn't secure.  The Git developers explicitly recommend against this.

Instead, you can follow the approach [outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment):

```
$ git config --global credential.helper \
    '!f() { echo username=author; echo "password=$GIT_TOKEN"; };f'
```

That will read the credential from the `GIT_TOKEN` environment variable and use the username `author`.

Or, if you'd like to run this in a script:

```
$ git config \
    -c credential.helper='!f() { echo username=author; echo "password=$GIT_TOKEN"; };f' \
    https://github.com/git/git.git
```

You'll obviously want to change the URL and the credentials.